# Building a docker image to run go applications

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, containers, docker-image

I am building a docker image on mac OS (Monterrey) with below dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest
WORKDIR /src
COPY go.* ./ 
RUN go mod download 
COPY . /src
RUN go build -o /main
ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

It works fine til the 3rd line and on the 4th it complains of

```
=> ERROR [4/6] RUN go mod download                                                         0.2s
------                                                                                           
 > [4/6] RUN go mod download:
#8 0.206 go mod download: no modules specified (see 'go help mod download')
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go mod download]: exit code: 1
```

Any clues what I am doing wrong while the dependencies are being downloaded?

Comment: This error could occur if there is no `go.mod` file in the folder where you run `go mod download`. So double check if your copy cmd `COPY go.* ./ ` places a valid `go.mod` file into your `/src` folder. Maybe it just copies another file from your working folder.

Comment: +1 @Andreas. As a novice go programmer, I clearly missed this. I have elaborated the fixed for other future novicer's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing couple of files from the Working directory as listed below. These are needed to download the dependencies.

```
Dockerfile //this was already in the folder. 
go.sum
go.mod
main.go
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using download do :

```
go mod tidy && go mod vendor
```

You need to specify which package to download when you use "mod download"

Comment: I replaced `RUN go mod download` with the line you suggested. Errored with `go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'`